# Get JIRA issue status time

Tags: jira

There is a status in my JIRA instance called "Ready For Test" at which the tester would validate and close the jira. I need to know the amount of time the JIRA is in that particular status since it was moved from "In Progress" to "Ready to Test".

Is there a JQL query that can do it? I need this time field to be exported to Excel as well so that I can name and shame people and ask them to close the JIRAs as soon as they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @SilenyHobit for the idea. Here is what I've done:

1. First installed JIRA Suite Utilities plugin (its FREE)
2. Added a custom field called RFTDate (date type control)
3. Added a post function in RFT transition to update RFTDate with current datetime

Voila!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible on clean Jira installation. There are two plugins I know providing this kind of functionality:

[Time in Status](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.obss.plugin.time-in-status) - self-explanatory

Enhancer Plugin (sorry, can't post more than two links) - adds a configurable time in status custom field, bt if I remember it correctly, it can display value only after you leave the status.

These are both paid, so that can be an issue.

Another option (if you're not using OnDemand) is the [Script Runner Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner). This plugin will allow you to create your own workflow postfunctions so you can store the "Ready to Test" transition date to one custom field and either calculate time and write it to another custom field when leaving that status or write a scripted field that will calculate and display current time since entering status. This solution is free (not counting your time to implement the functions).

Comment: Thanks. I think I will check out the 3rd option as buying a plugin would be a hard sell. Will let you know if it works as per my requirement.

Comment: Can I simply add a custom field and add a post function?

Comment: You'll add one custom field for storing the entry date and than write a script to write current date to that field and add it as a post function to a workflow. If the date is enough, you can leave it.

Comment: If you need the time passed, You need another script to compute it and add it to scripted field. All the necessary documentation can be found here: [link](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Script+Runner)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [Status Time Jira app](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221826/status-time?hosting=cloud&tab=overview). It provides reports on how much time passed in each status.

Once you enter your working calendar into the app, it takes your working schedule into account too. That is, "In Progress" time of an issue opened on Friday at 5 PM and closed on Monday at 9 AM, will be a few hours rather than 3 days. It has various other reports like assignee time, status entry dates, average/sum reports by any field(eg. average in progress time by project, average cycle time by issue creation month). And all these are available as gadgets on the dashboard too.

Here is the [online demo link](https://status-time.bloompeak.io/demo), you can see it in action and try.

As a **free** solution, you can try the limited version [Status Time Free](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222051/status-time-free).